# Cómo mantengo el valor de un campo select al querer editar los datos de un objeto (libro)? JAVA, SPRING, MVC, THYMELEAF

Tags: java, html, mvc, spring, thymeleaf

Tengo un HTML para **añadir** un libro y otro para **editarlo**. Al añadir un libro hay varios campos de **texto** y **número**: título, isbn, ejemplares. Pero hay otros que son campos **select**: año de publicación, editorial, autor. Mi duda es, cuando voy a editar los datos del libro, cómo mantengo la opción seleccionada en esos campos select? Cuando pulso editar se mantienen los valores en los campos de texto y números, menos en los select (vuelve a la primera opción).

Controlador:

```
    @GetMapping("/editar-libro/{id}")
    public String editarLibro(@PathVariable String id, ModelMap modelo) throws ErrorService {
        List<Autor> autores = autorRepositorio.findAll();
        modelo.put("autores", autores);

        List<Editorial> editoriales = editorialRepositorio.findAll();
        modelo.put("editoriales", editoriales);
        
        try{
            Libro libro = libroService.buscarLibroPorId(id);
            modelo.addAttribute("libro", libro);
        }catch(ErrorService e){
            modelo.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "editar-libro.html";
    }
```

Uno de los Select dentro del form:

```
<div>
     <select class="form-group" name="idEditorial" th:value="${libro.editorial}">
            <option>Editorial:</option>
            <option th:each="editorial : ${editoriales}" th:value="${editorial.id}" th:text="${editorial.nombre}" name="editorial"></option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el select te hace falta el th:field por el name y el th:value en el select no hace falta porque toma el th:value del option. Así por ejemplo:
th:field="*{idEditorial}"

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).